# Want to add "and" to if or switch

Tags: reporting-services, nested, switch-statement, iif

When I use this statement:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(FieldsImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives") 0,
Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") - Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives"))
```

However when I add an "AND"

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives") AND (Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implemented",0,
Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") - Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives"))
```

I get this error:

> Warning   1   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the
>   textrun ‘textbox58.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error:
>   Argument 'VarExpr' is not a valid value.

I am extremely new to SSRS, I've been working on this same issue for THREE DAYS and have officially lost my mind. Other searches get me close to my answer but no cigar. Once I get this piece working, I will need to add to it for when the GoalType is "Implementable" - PLUS I will need to do addition IIFs for when the SavingsGoal > ImplementedSavings or Implementable. PLEASE help and speak common English in your answers. I'm not a formally trained developer and programming terms confuse me sometimes. I've tried switch as well, same result. I'm sure it's some crazy syntax issue, but I swear I've tried 20 ways to Sunday and cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `AND`, it is that you are using aggregation in all cases except for the new condition you are adding. Try using `First` to your expression:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives") 
AND First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implemented", 0,
Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") - Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives"))
```

Comment: Excellent - now to add to that, I have this much of my additional code working:

Comment: If this answers your original question, please accept it as the answer (green tick) so  that the next person searching for this issue knows this solves it and upvote it.